# Initializing ngModel with data - AngularJS Bootstrap bs-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am maintaining a site that allows users to create a profile of sorts that will allow them to broadcast activities to a feed. I implement ng-grid to keep track of all the profiles that are created, and have created two buttons that allow users to create/edit these profiles. My only problem right now is, when users select a row on the grid and attempt to edit that specific row, the drop-down  menu is not auto-populated with the data from ngModel.

This is the part of the form I am having trouble with:

```
<select ng-model="source.canSendTo" ng-options="value.name for value in sourceCanSendTo" data-style="btn" bs-select></select>
```

And within the controller, I have sourceCanSendTo defined as:

```
$scope.sourceCanSendTo = [ {"id":"abc", "name": "ABC"}, {"id":bcd", "name": "BCD"} ... ];
```

On row selection, I simply set source = the selected item, and console.logs show that all the data is there. The other parts of the form are being populated properly (mainly s), and console.log($scope.source.canSendTo) shows that the original data is there, it's just that select is defaulted to being blank...how would I go about trying to pre-select certain elements on the drop-down select I currently have?

For example, if the profile has 'abc', 'bcd' selected, how can I make it so that when I edit that profile, the drop down box shows 'abc,bcd' instead of just "Nothing Selected"?

Edit: I previously responded to a comment inquiring about bs-select, saying that it simply controlled some CSS elements of the drop down box - seems like this is completely incorrect after a quick google search when everything else led to dead ends. Does anyone have any idea how to properly initialize the model with data so that when I preload my form, the 'can send to' drop down select actually has the selected options selected, as opposed to saying "Nothing Selected"? Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: You have `source.canSendTo` and `sourceCanSendTo` once with a dot and once without, is that intentional or a typo?

Comment: This is intentional. I really should go about renaming some of the variables so it's less confusing, this project was pretty confusing for me to pick up at first...

The sourceCanSendTo contains the values that user can select, and the selected values are stored into $scope.source.canSendTo. I push the $scope.source object into an array of objects on the ngGrid used to manage all the profiles. Sorry for the confusion :x

Comment: What is the `bs-select`? Is it a third party directive?

Comment: What is the structure of the data that you are getting back from the server?

Comment: @nramirez - I get the data back from selected row of ngGrid where I store all the data. There are a bunch of other properties, but for 'canSendTo' property of $scope.source, I get data back as shown in my post (objects in the array $scope.sourceCanSendTo are bound to $scope.source.canSendTo, e.g., if 'ABC' is selected, the object {"id":"abc", "name":"ABC"} is pushed into $scope.source.canSendTo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are binding source.canSendTo to the name (value.name) of sourceCanSendTo then you just need to initially have an structure binding the names which had been saved, something like this:

```
source.canSendTo = ['abc', 'bcd']; //And all the selected values
```

So you need to construct your source.canSendTo property to this structure.

PS: If you show how you bring your data from the server, I can help you to construct the source.canSendTo property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! On row selection within ngGrid, I set $scope.source = selectedRow, so $scope.source.canSendTo contains all the values it needs at this point. Do I need to actually push the objects in one by one? (I am trying to bind objects, and I let users select these objects based on the "name" attribute of the object)

Comment: yes you need to push only the name to the source.CanSendTo Property, you can accomplish it with a for. Its better for you to push Id instead of names you can change your ng-options directive to show names but bind id like so ng-options="value.Id as value.name for value in sourceCanSendTo".

Comment: @athoi then you can persist the id and resolve initially an array of Id into you source.canSendTo like source.canSendTo = ['abc, 'bcd']

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your post helped me a lot when I looked over it again while debugging last night! I'd give you an upvote, but I'm at 15- reputation..

Answer (score 0):

$scope.canSendTo must be initialized with a reference to the selected option.

```
var initialSelection = 0;
$scope.source = { canSendTo : [ {"id":"abc", "name": "ABC"}, {"id":bcd", "name": "BCD"} ... ] };
$scope.canSendTo = $scope.source.canSendTo[initialSelection];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what was wrong with my code - seems like the data being stored in the model wasn't the same as what was in ngOptions, played around a bit with ngOptions and managed to get something that works. Working snippet of code:

```
<select ng-model="sendTo.name" ng-option="value.name as value.name for value in sourceCanSendTo" data-style="btn" multiple bs-select>
```

(Realized that the variable being used for ngModel was a fairly ambiguous in terms of naming convention, changed it)